# Update post from plug-in not fully working …

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plug-in in which I'm updating a post content and create a custom field using

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'thesis_post_image', 'http://www.nurseryrhymesonline.net/images/' . $meta);

$my_post = array(
    'ID' => $post->ID,
    'post_content' => $cont
    );

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

It is working fine and the content and the custom fields are exactly as I wanted BUT although I can see the content and the custom field at the post edit page it seems like not updating the DB unless I manually hit the Update button.
I tried without any success have a new loop in which I changing the post status to 'draft' and back to 'published' and also to 'private' and back to 'published' and even 'pending' and back BUT nothing helped and it doesn't simulate the manual clicking on the update button.

Any Idea how to simulate clicking on Update button from a plug-in

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the past that using `$post->ID` does not work very well in a plugin. Maybe `get_the_id()` will help. Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).